# Shell script run by launchd in MacOS can't create at job

Tags: bash, mac, sudo, launchd, at

I'm using the privileges.app to grant users temp admin privileges.
Because I need to have password auth and justification enabled via config, I can't use the build-in feature to limit the duration of the given privileges to 15min.

So I created a launchd to call a script that periodically (once per minute) checks if user have been added to the admin group and, if it detects a new member, create a job to demote the user using atrun. Full Disk Access for Terminal and atrun is enabled.

The launchD gets properly created, the script also gets created and runs properly.
It successfully detects changes in the admin group and tries to create the job for atrun, which does not work. Running the same script not via launchd, but in Terminal with sudo works perfectly fine.

What do I have to do for this to work?

I'm deploying the script via Mobile Iron Core, if that is relevant.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# created 17.10.2023 - Manuel Frank

# create .plist to launch script and keep it running 
sudo defaults write /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist Label -string "admincheck"

sudo defaults write /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist ProgramArguments -array -string /bin/sh -string "/Library/Application Support/com.mobileiron.mac.agent/admincheck.sh"

sudo defaults write /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist RunAtLoad -boolean yes

sudo defaults write /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist KeepAlive -boolean yes

sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist

# load .plist, sleep 10 if system is slow
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist
sleep 10

# create script for .plist to launch
cat << 'EOF' > /Library/Application\ Support/com.mobileiron.mac.agent/admincheck.sh
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10

# check for local user in admin group, remove root & hidden admin account from output
localadmin=$(dscacheutil -q group -a name admin | awk '$1 == "users:" { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { if (($i != "root") && ($i != "admin")) { print $i } } }')

# define time after which admin user are demoted
TEMPSECONDS=900

    # while-loop to check if user have been added to admin group
    while [ -z "$localadmin" ]; do
            sleep 60
            localadmin=$(dscacheutil -q group -a name admin | awk '$1 == "users:" { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { if (($i != "root") && ($i != "admin")) { print $i } } }')
            localuser=$(dscl . list /Users | grep -v "^_\|daemon\|root\|nobody\|admin")  
                # admin has been found, queue job for demoting after TEMPSECONDS
                if [ -n "$localadmin" ]; then
                # Checks if atrun is launched or not 
                if ! launchctl list|grep -q com.apple.atrun; then launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist; fi
                # job to demote user
                echo "#!/bin/sh
                    for User in $localuser
                    do
                    /usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -d $localuser -t user admin
                    done
                    
                    launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist
                        
                    exit $?" | at -t "$(date -v+"$TEMPSECONDS"S "+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S")"
                exit 0
                fi
    done
    
# unload .plist to ensure script is not run before job is finished. .plist will be loaded after job finishes.    
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/admincheck.plist

exit 0

EOF

exit 0
```